# One-click unsubscribe Amazon SES

Tags: amazon-ses

[image: Unsubscribe button]

Hello everyone.
I am trying to add the Unsubscribe button to my header while sending with my Amazon SES account, but it doesn't appear on Yahoo emails.
Can please someone help me?

```
List-Unsubscribe: <https://nutrition.co/?address=x&topic=x>, <mailto:unsubscribe@ nutrition.co?subject=TopicUnsubscribe>
List-Unsubscribe-Post: List-Unsubscribe=One-Click
```

I tried to add this to parameters on my header, but the Unsubscribe button didn't appear.